# How do I strip the floats from the last column, listed/labelled by the name in the first column?

Tags: python

What I'm talking about is this series of sensor readings in a text file:

> Thermometer1 - 22:00 - 72.4
> Thermometer1 - 22:01 - 76.0
> Thermometer1 - 22:02 - 79.1
> Thermometer1 - 22:03 - 75.6
> Thermometer1 - 22:04 - 71.2
> Thermometer1 - 22:05 - 71.4
> Thermometer1 - 22:06 - 69.2
> Thermometer1 - 22:07 - 65.2
> Thermometer1 - 22:08 - 62.8
> Thermometer1 - 22:09 - 61.4
> Thermometer1 - 22:10 - 64.0
> Thermometer1 - 22:11 - 67.5
> Thermometer1 - 22:12 - 69.4
> Thermometer2 - 22:01 - 69.5
> Thermometer2 - 22:02 - 70.1
> Thermometer2 - 22:03 - 71.3
> Thermometer2 - 22:04 - 71.5
> Thermometer2 - 22:05 - 69.8
> Hygrometer1 - 22:04 - 45.2
> Hygrometer1 - 22:05 - 45.3
> Hygrometer1 - 22:06 - 45.1
> Hygrometer2 - 22:04 - 44.4
> Hygrometer2 - 22:05 - 43.9
> Hygrometer2 - 22:06 - 44.9
> Hygrometer2 - 22:07 - 43.8
> Hygrometer2 - 22:08 - 42.1

Just for clarity's sake, my full task is that I need to:

1. Strip the floats (temperature/humidity readings)
2. Group them by sensor name
3. Get the mean and standard deviation of each sensor's readings
4. Check if the mean/standard deviation is within limits
5. Print out the the answer to 4 along the lines of "thermometer1 is not precise enough"

I have a few ideas how to do 1: I know literal_eval from 'ast' and genfromtxt from 'numpy' can just get me a list of the floats. But I'm not sure how to get from 1 to 2 in a way that I can then perform 3 thru 5 on each sensor individually.

Comment: please put any attempt you currently have instead of just your problem statement

Comment: @JoranBeasley Like I said, I can get a big array of the floats with "genfromtxt", but it looks like: [72.4 76.  79.1 75.6 71.2 71.4 69.2 65.2 62.8 61.4 64.  67.5 69.4 69.5
 70.1 71.3 71.5 69.8 45.2 45.3 45.1 44.4 43.9 44.9 43.8 42.1]

The problem is I don't know have any idea how to group them up.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pandas` to do this efficiently:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('a.txt', delimiter='-', header=None)

In [4]: df.groupby(0)[[2]].agg([np.mean, np.std])
Out[4]:
                       2
                    mean       std
0
Hygrometer1    45.200000  0.100000
Hygrometer2    43.820000  1.056882
Thermometer1   69.630769  5.397898
Thermometer2   70.440000  0.904434
```

Now you can perform number 3 & 4 on this data

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a library:

I am assuming you have loaded the file's contents into a variable named `data`

```
sensors = {}
lines = [line for line in data.split('\n') if line] # filter out empty lines
for line in lines: # iterate over each line
    elements = line.split(' ') # split the line by spaces
    sensor_name = elements[0] # the first of the elements is the sensor's name
    value = float(elements[-1]) # the last of the elements is the data
    # add the data to a list in a dict according to the sensor name
    if sensor_name in sensors.keys() 
        sensors[sensor_name].append(value)
    else:
        sensors[sensor_name] = [value]
```

This will result in a dictionary of lists where the keys are the names of the sensor

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to extract floats numbers.

---

**For example:**

```
from re import search

file = open('file.txt', mode = 'r')

floats = list()

for _ in file.readlines():
    if result := search(r"(\d*\.\d*)", _):
        floats.append(result.group(1))

print(floats)
```

---

**Output:**

```
['72.4', '76.0', '79.1', '75.6', '71.2', '71.4', '69.2', '65.2', '62.8', '61.4', '64.0', '67.5', '69.4', '69.5', '70.1', '71.3', '71.5', '69.8', '45.2', '45.3', '45.1', '44.4', '43.9', '44.9', '43.8', '42.1']
```

---

**Update:**

You can do this to get all the information in the dictionary.

```
from re import search

file = open('file.txt', mode = 'r')

floats = dict()

for _ in file.readlines():
    if result := search(r"(\w+) - (\d+:\d+) - (\d*\.\d*)", _):
        data = {
            'name': result.group(1),
            'time': result.group(2),
            'value': result.group(3),

        }
        if result.group(1) not in floats:
            floats[result.group(1)] = [data]
        else:
            floats[result.group(1)].append(data)

print(floats)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Thermometer1': [{'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:00', 'value': '72.4'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:01', 'value': '76.0'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:02', 'value': '79.1'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:03', 'value': '75.6'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:04', 'value': '71.2'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:05', 'value': '71.4'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:06', 'value': '69.2'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:07', 'value': '65.2'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:08', 'value': '62.8'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:09', 'value': '61.4'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:10', 'value': '64.0'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:11', 'value': '67.5'}, {'name': 'Thermometer1', 'time': '22:12', 'value': '69.4'}], 'Thermometer2': [{'name': 'Thermometer2', 'time': '22:01', 'value': '69.5'}, {'name': 'Thermometer2', 'time': '22:02', 'value': '70.1'}, {'name': 'Thermometer2', 'time': '22:03', 'value': '71.3'}, {'name': 'Thermometer2', 'time': '22:04', 'value': '71.5'}, {'name': 'Thermometer2', 'time': '22:05', 'value': '69.8'}], 'Hygrometer1': [{'name': 'Hygrometer1', 'time': '22:04', 'value': '45.2'}, {'name': 'Hygrometer1', 'time': '22:05', 'value': '45.3'}, {'name': 'Hygrometer1', 'time': '22:06', 'value': '45.1'}], 'Hygrometer2': [{'name': 'Hygrometer2', 'time': '22:04', 'value': '44.4'}, {'name': 'Hygrometer2', 'time': '22:05', 'value': '43.9'}, {'name': 'Hygrometer2', 'time': '22:06', 'value': '44.9'}, {'name': 'Hygrometer2', 'time': '22:07', 'value': '43.8'}, {'name': 'Hygrometer2', 'time': '22:08', 'value': '42.1'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but I already knew how to get the floats by other methods. I just didn't know how to group them properly.

Comment: @Flipscuba I edited my answer, check to see if this is what you want